# Map aggregate query result to correct attributes of POJO

Tags: spring-data, aggregation-framework, spring-webflux, spring-data-mongodb

I have a collection named Location which has couple of attributes of which I want to fetch only country code and country name.

When I'm using below aggregation query in Spring Data, all the attributes are getting mapped to the _id attribute of Location.java and not to individual countryCode and countryName attribute of the List. Please help me resolve the same.

```
@Repository
public class AggregateQueryRepository {
    
@Autowired
ReactiveMongoTemplate reactiveMongoTemplate;
 
public Flux<Location> getAllCountryCodeAndCountry() {
        Aggregation aggregation = newAggregation(group("countryCode", "countryName")
        );
        return reactiveMongoTemplate.aggregate(aggregation, "location", Location.class);
    }
}
```

Currently each object of the result looks like below:

```
{ "_id": "{\"countryCode\": \"IN\", \"countryName\": \"India\"}" }
```

I want to map it to something like below:

```
{
{ "_id": null,
"countryCode": "ÏN"
"countryName": "India"
},
....
.....
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you must have it separately, you can consider using [`$first` aggregation accumulator](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/first/#mongodb-group-grp.-first):

```java
Aggregation aggregation = newAggregation(
    group("countryCode", "countryName")
        .first("countryCode").as("countryCode")
        .first("countryName").as("countryName")
);

return reactiveMongoTemplate.aggregate(aggregation, "location", Location.class);
```

...or alternatively [$replaceRoot aggregation stage](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/replaceRoot/):

```java
Aggregation aggregation = newAggregation(
    group("countryCode", "countryName"),
    replaceRoot("_id")
);

return reactiveMongoTemplate.aggregate(aggregation, "location", Location.class);
```